# How can I connect via Symfony 4 to mySQL database created with MAMP?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, database-connection

I created a database in MAMP called "project".

In my `.env` file I added this line:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/project
```

Now I want to run

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

But I get an error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

my doctrine configurations:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: Can you show please the doctrine configuration?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Where do I find it?

Comment: you mean `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`?

Comment: yes exactly please add it

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Added it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it!

in the file "config/packages/doctrine.yaml" I had to add this line

> unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

This means change this:

```
 dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

into

```
 dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Comment: I can give you some background on your error: if you use `localhost` it has special meaning and mysql-client lib tries to connect via socket. as your socket is not in one of the default locations you have to give dbal the exact location.
You also can change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` to enforce a TCP connection, which would not use the socket.

Comment: @Rufinus I tied to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` but then I got the error "Connection failed"

Comment: You can also put a unix_socket param in  the DATABASE_URL of your environment file e.g. `.env.local` :

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/dbname?unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 6):

Got the same problem. Added the unix_socket and changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost works on MAMP 5.5.

doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/mydb
```

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

to this:

```
url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can also try is setting the mysql server expliclitly

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:         local_api
                user:           root
                password:       null
                host:           localhost
                driver:         pdo_mysql
                server_version: '5.5' # in case you are using mysql 5.5
```

Comment: I have the same problem today. It's 5 years later after this question date. 

Terrible!
Why do maintainers can't make this setting easier?