# Doctrine won't connect to MAMP mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony4, mamp

**EDIT: I have since resolved my issue thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908912/12296041**

I have started learning Symfony for a school project, and I was following a tutorial from Symfony's website, but for some reason, Doctrine doesn't manage to connect to MySQL database I have running on my computer. I'm on a Macbook, using MAMP to run a local MySQL server.
Whenever I try to execute any doctrine commands that interact with the database such as `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` it never works.

So far, I have checked that I could indeed connect to the database using PHPMyAdmin. I have also tried to change the `DATABASE_URL` in the `.env` file, but this hasn't solved my issue.
I have also tried creating a symbolic link with `sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock` but that didn't work either.

This is what my `.env` file looks like:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# For a PostgreSQL database, use: "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11"
# IMPORTANT: You MUST also configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8888/db
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

And I get this error when trying to create a database with doctrine:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Anything that can point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't the default port for MySQL in MAMP `8889` ?

Comment: @Cid I don't think so, at least I've always used port `8888` ever since the first time I fired up MAMP

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cid, port is 8889 by default for MySQL in MAMP.
You can also try to replace 127.0.0.1 by localhost.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. As I said, the port is 8888 on my computer.

Comment: What's the port of your webserver? My guess is that there is a conflict between your webserver (Apache or Nginx) and MySQL. Try to set MySQL port to 8889 and set your login URL as described above: DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:8889/pweb2

Comment: I have gone into my MAMP settings and reset the ports. My configuration is now:
`Apache: 8888`
`Nginx: 8888`
`Mysql: 8889`

Comment: Yeah. I can login into it fine using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can you try port 3306 instead of 8888 or 8889? It's just a try, but this could it...

Comment: Second stupid question, the database `pweb2` does exist, right?